# position absolute inside absolute

Tags: html, css

behavior of positioning an element as `absolute` seems to have changed.

I have

```
<div> // position relative
<ul> // position absolute
  ul:before // position absolute
  <li> // background color on hover
</ul>
</div>
```

and still, the `before` pseudo element, is limited to the `ul`. and is not visible beyond the ul no matter. even if the `position` is changed to `fixed`

this seems the output

[image]

```css
div {
    border: 4px solid #525454;

    width: 14em;
 height: 1em;
 position: relative;

}

div ul {
 
 background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:110%;
    max-height: 10.68571429rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(34,36,38,.15);



}
div > ul > li:hover{
  background-color:beige;
}
div > ul > li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
        padding:5px 10px;

}
div ul::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;

    width: 50px;
    height: 102px;
    background: linear-gradient(black, yellow, red);
    top: -21px;
    left: 5px;
   z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>1</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wanna have background for the whole menu so you should add `background:linear-gradient(black,yellow,red)` to `div ul`

So, CSS should changed to be like that

```css
div
{
 border:4px solid #525454;
 width:14em;
 height:1em;
 position:relative
}

div ul
{
 background-color:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 top:110%;
 max-height:10.68571429rem;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:auto;
 width:calc(100% + 2px);
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background:#FFF;
 box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0 rgba(34,36,38,.15);
 background:linear-gradient(black,yellow,red)
}

div > ul > li:hover
{
 background-color:#f5f5dc
}

div > ul > li
{
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 padding:5px 10px
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```